# There is no property mapped to the column 'CleaningEmployees.Id' used in a data operation

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm working on a .NET Core c# project. I'm using Entity Framework Core to connect to a database. I already created it before and it worked. Then I changed the datatype of an `id` column from `uint` to `int` and now I can't recreate it.

I used the command

```
dotnet ef database update 0
```

so I don't have to drop the column and recreate it.

I get this error:

[image]

Since that didn't work, I tried changing it back but now that doesn't work anymore either. I also don't understand what this error message is trying to tell me.

Does anyone know what the problem could be?

Here are the classes:

```
using System;

namespace CarRental.Classes
{
    public class CleaningEmployee : Employee
    {
        public CleaningEmployee(string firstName, string lastName, string emailAddress, string street, uint number, string town, DateTime birthday, string phone, string phoneMobile, bool isAvailable) : base(firstName, lastName, emailAddress, street, number, town, birthday, phone, phoneMobile, isAvailable)
        {
        }

        public CleaningEmployee()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

This class inherits from the Employee class:

```
using System;

namespace CarRental.Classes
{
    public class Employee : Person
    {
        public Employee(string firstName, string lastName, string emailAddress, string street, uint number, string town, DateTime birthday, string phone, string phoneMobile, bool isAvailable) : base(firstName, lastName, emailAddress, street, number, town, birthday, phone, phoneMobile)
        {
            IsAvailable = isAvailable;
        }

        public Employee()
        {
        }

        public bool IsAvailable { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And the employee class inherits from the person class:

```
using System;

namespace CarRental.Classes
{
    public abstract class Person
    {
        protected Person()
        {
        }

        protected Person(string firstName, string lastName, string emailAddress, string street, uint number, string town, DateTime birthday, string phone, string phoneMobile)
        {
            FirstName = firstName;
            LastName = lastName;
            EmailAddress = emailAddress;
            Street = street;
            Number = number;
            Town = town;
            Birthday = birthday;
            Phone = phone;
            PhoneMobile = phoneMobile;
        }

        public uint Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
        public string Street { get; set; }
        public uint Number { get; set; }
        public string Town { get; set; }
        public DateTime Birthday { get; set; }
        public string Phone { get; set; }
        public string PhoneMobile { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here's the `id` property that I've changed from `uint` to `int` and then back to `int` again.

I don't know if it has anything to do with the issue but here's the seed method I use:

```
// Creating cleaningEmployee dummy data
CleaningEmployee cleaningEmployee1 = new CleaningEmployee("Peter", "Hueber", "peter.huerber@carrental.ch",
                "hueberstrasse", 3, "Zug", new DateTime(2000, 3, 12), "341 324 234 23 12", "234 423 243 43 43", true);
            cleaningEmployee1.Id = 1;
            
CleaningEmployee cleaningEmployee2 = new CleaningEmployee("Samuel", "Müller", "samuel.müller@carrental.ch",
                "müllerstrasse", 3, "Zug", new DateTime(2001, 4, 12), "341 234 234 43 12", "234 234 243 54 43", true);
            cleaningEmployee2.Id = 2;
            
modelBuilder.Entity<CleaningEmployee>().HasData(cleaningEmployee1, cleaningEmployee2);
```

Comment: Go to your database and see if there is a colum `Id` and note which type it has. Check if your migration did actually work.

Comment: The type is bigint and the migration seems to have worked

Comment: But in your code it is uint. Bigint in SQL is `long` in C#. Or `Int64`. Both should work

Comment: Yes i dont know why that is, all the uint propertys are bigint in the db

Comment: Change them from `unit` to `long` then.

Comment: Tried it, but that didnt help i still get the same error

Answer (score 7):

For Anyone who lands in this question! Faced the same issue as I was updating the migration files directly forgot to update [migration_name].Designer.cs partial file.

Make sure the Designer file reflects the latest db schema and properties.

Comment: This! Thanks man, I always forget the designer file... :/

Comment: I don't know how to update migration designer file. Guidance please

Comment: Hi  @ArhamAnees If you can not find the file it is indent under [migration_name].cs, you need to apply the same changes you did in migration file there so if you have renamed a column try to find it in the designer file and rename there too